# How to verify if a certain value is present in a custom attribute using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

Lets say we have a custom attribute named **data-content**. Now lets look for the html markup :

```
 <h1 data-content="one two three four">Hello</h1>
```

I want a **Javascript** / **jQuery** function that can do something like this :

```
 verify.contains("h1", "two"); // => true
 verify.contains("h1", "five"); // => false
```

Or

```
 $("h1").verifyContains("two"); // => true
 $("h1").verifyContains("five"); // => false
```

So, how to do it ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: do you want to check if there is any `h1` tag that its `data-content` attribute contains `two`? or you want to check if an explicit tag's `data-content` attribute contains the word `two`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Attribute Contains Word Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

```js
var verify = {
  contains: function(selector, content) {
    return Boolean($(selector + '[data-content~=' + content + ']').length)
  }
}

console.log(verify.contains("h1", "two"))
console.log(verify.contains("h1", "five"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 data-content="one two three four">Hello</h1>
```

**Jquery plugin function**

```js
$.fn.verifyContains = function(content) {
  return $(this).is('[data-content~=' + content + ']')
}

console.log($("h1").verifyContains("two"))
console.log($("h1").verifyContains("five"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 data-content="one two three four">Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JavaScript:

```
function myFunc(tag, val) {
  let x = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].getAttribute("data-content"); 
  return x.includes(val)
}
```

You can add further checks, if the attribute even exists on the element, or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the element's attribute value and check the string index.

```js
var verify = {
  contains : function(selector, value) {
    return this.attributeContains(selector, 'data-content', value);
  },
  attributeContains : function(selector, attr, value) {
    return document.querySelector(selector).getAttribute(attr).indexOf(value) > -1;
  }
};

console.log(verify.contains('h1', 'two'));  // => true
console.log(verify.contains('h1', 'five')); // => false
```

```html
<h1 data-content="one two three four">Hello</h1>
```